# Text Search inside XML nodes with a specific Attribute in DB2 express-C

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Have installed DB2 express-C 9.7 on Win7, and am using the DB2 Text Search engine.

I have one requirement to search inside all XML nodes having a specific attribute. Have tried these options:

statement.executeQuery("xquery " +
"for $i in db2-fn:sqlquery(\"SELECT doc FROM orders WHERE CONTAINS(doc, '@xpath:''/order//@key[. contains (\"\"java\"\")]''') = 1\")/order " +                  "return $i/customer");

statement.executeQuery("xquery " +
"for $i in db2-fn:sqlquery(\"SELECT doc FROM orders WHERE CONTAINS(doc, '@xpath:''/order//@key[.. contains (\"\"java\"\")]''') = 1\")/order " +                  "return $i/customer");

Here am unsuccessfully trying to search for all those xml documents which have 'java' inside all child elements (of 'order' node) having an attribute 'key'.

May anyone please tell me what should be the right query for this.

Thanks.

Comment: might be interesting for you - all db2 xml possibilities http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/